# Simplify JavaScript collision detection with offset

Tags: javascript, collision

I am working on a background project that is a little interactive. Now I am using some collision detection to draw some lines and stuff.

The code I have works great but it is very bulky and hard to read.

```
if (background.allPixels[i].location.x - drawLineBetweenPixelRange < background.allPixels[j].location.x + background.allPixels[j].width &&
    background.allPixels[i].location.x + background.allPixels[i].width + drawLineBetweenPixelRange > background.allPixels[j].location.x &&
    background.allPixels[i].location.y - drawLineBetweenPixelRange < background.allPixels[j].location.y + background.allPixels[j].height &&
    background.allPixels[i].location.y + background.allPixels[i].height + drawLineBetweenPixelRange > background.allPixels[j].location.y)
```

It comes down to running this for the x and y coordinates:

```
var result = (x - a < y + b) && (x + b + a > y)
```

Can this be simplified?

I was hoping if the check itself could be shortened by taking stuff out that might counter eachother.

Answer (score 3):

### Bug #1

Your code does not follow pattern `(x - a < y + b) && (x + b + a > y)` but `(x - a < y + b1) || (x + b2 + a > y)` instead. <del>So our refactored formula is moot!</del> <sup>obsolete</sup>

---

### Bug #2

A collision is detected when **any** of the guards trigger, not when **all**.

---

### Proposed Solution

Solving both bugs, we could refactor Nikko Khresna's method:

```
function detectCollision(source, target, line) {
  return 
       source.location.x < target.location.x + target.width + line
    || source.location.x + source.width + line > target.location.x
    || source.location.y < target.location.y + target.height + line
    || source.location.y + source.height + line > target.location.y
  ;
}
```

and you can call it as follows

```
const collision = detectCollision(
  background.allPixels[i], background.allPixels[j], drawLineBetweenPixelRange);
```

---

<sub>Obsolete section because OP made a mistake in the formula: I'll keep it for historical reasons :)</sub>

### Formula (Obsolete)

The way I see it, we could rewrite your expression:

> ```
> var result = (x - a < y + b) && (x + b + a > y)
> ```

as

```
var result = (x - a - b < y) && (x + b + a > y)
```

and further as

```
var result = (x - (a + b) < y) && (x + (a + b) > y)
```

now we can substitute `(a + b)` with `offset`

```
var result = (x - offset < y) && (x + offset > y)
```

which means `x` and `y` have to be within `offset` distance of each other (`|x-y|` = `abs(x-y)`)

```
var result = Math.abs(x - y) < offset
```

Now you can substitute `x`, `y` and `offset` with your variables, and - as suggested in the other answer - use a method that calculates this collision for you.

Comment: Thanks. This was what i was looking for and it looks very promising i will try it out as soon as i got time. I will let you know.

Comment: I understand how my formula wasn't correct cause target width and source width can be different from each other. 

I do not understand your proposed solution tho. You are using the OR operators, the way i see it this will always translate to true, because if `source.location.x < target.location.x + target.width + line` is false, `source.location.x + source.width + line > target.location.x` will always be true. 

Am i missing something or did you mean to use the AND operator ?

Answer (score 1):

first, accessing those properties all over again is really confusing

```
let bgI = background.allPixels[i]
let locI = bgI.location
let line = drawLineBetweenPixelRange
let bgJ = background.allPixels[j]
let locJ = bgJ.location


if (locI.x - line < locJ.x + bgJ.width &&
    locI.x + bgI.width + line > locJ.x &&
    locI.y - line < locJ.y + bgJ.height &&
    so on and so on...
```

second, redefining all those variables all over again really hurts efficiency

```
function detectCollision(background, line) {
    let bgI = background.allPixels[i]
    let bgJ = background.allPixels[j]
    let locI = bgI.location
    let locJ = bgJ.location

    if (locI.x - line < locJ.x + bgJ.width &&
        locI.x + bgI.width + line > locJ.x &&
        locI.y - line < locJ.y + bgJ.height &&
        so on and so on....
}

detectCollision(background, drawLineBetweenPixelRange)
```

hope it helps

Comment: Welcome to Code Review. Please go into more detail how it "hurts efficiency". Also note that your function uses global variables `i` and `j` and therefore will be a a nightmare to debug.

Comment: Inefficient because: t gives space for human error, is not DRY, responsibilty of methods are not well separated. `i` and `j` could be anythig, global var, index of iteration, etc. So I'll leave the real implementation of `i` and `j`  to OP.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Since this code does not run again on any other place i hadn't thought about putting it in its own function. I will think about applying this but is not the answer i am looking for. I whas hoping if the check itself could be shortened by taking stuff out that might counter eachother.

Comment: @NikkoKhresna Additional information should be put into your post. Please [edit] accordingly. Comments may get deleted when they aren't needed anymore and don't have a history, whereas posts do.